# FormCollection is null when sending a blob file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I'm trying to send a javascript blob of size "4682933" and type "image/png" which was converted from a Base64String. I'm not able to retrieve anything on the server. FormCollection object is always null.

Here's my code for making the client request to the server:

```
    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append("data", Blobx);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.open('POST', '/Patient/pdfSavefile'); 
    request.send(formData);
```

Here's my controller code for retrieving the file.

```
        public bool pdfSavefile(FormCollection formdata)
        {
            var data = formdata["data"];
        }
```

I have the following in my webconfig file

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" requestValidationMode="2.0" executionTimeout="10000" />
```

I have tried everything, nothing really works.

my code for converting Base64String to Blob

```
function base64ToBlob(base64, mime) 
{
    mime = mime || '';
    var sliceSize = 1024;
    var byteChars = window.atob(base64);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0, len = byteChars.length; offset < len; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteChars.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: mime});
}
```

Comment: so, are you posting the file as a base64 string to `pdfSavefile` under the field `data`?

Comment: If I remember correctly, formdata never shows in a console.log its content.

Comment: @scgough No I'm posting it as form data with the payload that is the blob converted from Base64String

Comment: Would it be feasible to post the base64 string then convert to a file (and do whatever) on the server side?

Comment: @xale94 I'm not viewing it on console. I do see that Blob data I'm trying to send does contain data put somehow I don't receive anything on the server side

Comment: @scgough it takes a lot of memory plus I don't really know how to do it

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba ok - in the past I've done this in an API - post a file as a base64 string and convert to file on the server side then do what I need to with it

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much never use `FormCollection`, but if memory serves, it only accepts string key-value pairs. Any posted files would either be found in the `Request.Files` collection or need to be handled individually as `HttpPostedFileBase` params. For example, if all you're posting is this file, all you should need to do is change the action signature to:

```
    public bool pdfSavefile(HttpPostedFileBase data)
```

If you do have other form fields that are being posted, I'd suggest creating a view model instead of relying on `FormCollection`. The MVC modelbinder is one of the main benefits of MVC and you're pretty much throwing that away completely using `FormCollection`.